# Laravel and Vue templating error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5, vue.js

I am using vue for the first time within laravel 5.3 and I am currently able to get my data using a Jquery AJAX request within vue however i am having some trouble displaying it. This is currently my script: This is my view:

```
<li>

    <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->

    <ul class="menu" id="messagesArea">
        <messages></messages>
    </ul>
</li>
<!-- Further Down the page -->
<template id="messages-template">
  <div v-for="messages in list">
    <p>
    @{{ messages.name }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/messages.js">

</script>
```

This is messages.js

```
Vue.component('messages', {
  template: '#messages-template',
  data: function (){
  return {
    list:[]
  };},
  created (){

    $.getJSON('ap/test', function(messages){
      this.list = messages;
    }.bind(this))
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#messagesArea'
});
```

This is what is recieved via the ajax:

```
list: Array[5]
0: Object
created_at: "2016-12-05 16:26:03"
id: 5
infoContent: "{\"rows\":2,\"content\":{\"Description\":{\"curSize\":12,\"name\":\"Description\",\"Type\":\"string\",\"isLarge\":false,\"value\":\"There was a problem with this!\",\"row\":1}}}"
name: "Issue 5"
progression: "1"
project: "7"
updated_at: "2016-12-05 16:26:03"
user: "1"
1: Object
created_at: "2016-12-05 16:25:45"
id: 4
infoContent: "{\"rows\":2,\"content\":{\"Description\":{\"curSize\":12,\"name\":\"Description\",\"Type\":\"string\",\"isLarge\":false,\"value\":\"There was a problem with this!\",\"row\":1}}}"
name: "Issue 4"
progression: "1"
project: "7"
updated_at: "2016-12-05 16:25:45"
user: "1"
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

I am having trouble looping through theese and getting the data out of them. Could i get some help with this thanks.

Please ask if you need the whole view or anything else.
I have changed the  as recommended by in the first answer however i am getting these error:

Error 1:

```
    [Vue warn]: Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements:
<div v-for="messages in list">
    <p>
    {{ messages.name }}
    </p>
  </div>
```

Error 2:

```
    vue.js:513 [Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node. 
(found in component <messages>)
```

These are the errors i was getting before i changed when my template was like this:

```
<template id="messages-template" v-for="messages in list">
  <p>
  @{{ messages.name }}
  </p>
</template>
```

Error 1

```
    [Vue warn]: Property or method "messages" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in component <messages>)
```

Error 2

```
[Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <messages>:
```

Error 3

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Proxy.eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:8132), <anonymous>:2:45)
at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.js:2927)
at VueComponent.<anonymous> (vue.js:2335)
at Watcher.get (vue.js:1643)
at new Watcher (vue.js:1635)
at VueComponent.Vue._mount (vue.js:2334)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:5916)
at VueComponent.Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:8199)
at init (vue.js:2648)
at createComponent (vue.js:4030)
```

Comment: What errors do you get

Comment: Why do you have `@` in `  @{{ messages.name }}`

Comment: The @ is to stop laravel blade engine running it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happening because you have put `v-for` in template itself, you have to put in inside template, in another div or some other element, like following:

```
<template id="messages-template">
  <div>
    <div v-for="messages in list">
      <p> @{{ messages && messages.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

### Reason of the error:

> vue.js:513 [Vue warn]: Multiple root nodes returned from render function. Render function should return a single root node. 
>   (found in component )

You were getting this error because in your component template you can not use `v-for` directive on a root element. For example following is not allowed because your component can have multiple root elements:

```
<template id="messages-template">
    <div v-for="messages in list">
      <p> @{{ messages && messages.name }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I just changed to this and im getting more error. I shall add them into my main post

Comment: @RPSystems You can, but just making this change should not have given you more errors.

Comment: Ok sorry im bad wording. I meant I am getting different error.

Comment: @RPSystems Yes, you can add a Edited Section in the question and add these errors, which will help.

Comment: I have added all the error i was getting from after the edit and before the edit. I posted this quite late at night sorry